# How to set a retention policy in JFrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray, jfrog-container-registry

I'm looking for a way to set retention period in JFrog Arttifactory, which will remove SNAPSHOT versions older than 100 days.

If any teams need particular files need to be keep in Artifactory forever, need to exclude some path alone in that repo from retention policy and other directories should be removed as per the retention policy.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://jfrog.com/blog/advanced-cleanup-using-artifactory-query-language-aql/) you should be able to build an [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language)
that will help you find the artifacts you would like to delete and then use the code from the article to delete it.

Other than that, JFrog has a few built in plug-ins on the [github](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup) page - you can see if one of them suits you.

Comment: Answers that consist of links should really include the salient details of said links in the answer itself. When your links die/change, your post loses what value it has.